# QT 5.7 video element freezing when device using high CPU or RAM

Tags: qt, qml, gstreamer, qtquick2

I'm playing with a video reel app that uses a qml video elements [1].

The app just loops through a list of video urls and then plays them, shuffling 3 video elements so that a user can jump forward or backwards by a single video at a time.

This is all done in qtquick/javascript.

I've noticed that on high system CPU or RAM usage (>50% of either) the app will occasionally freeze.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x73774dbc in __lll_lock_wait (futex=0x2bd57e0, private=0)
    at /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.23-r0/git/nptl/lowlevellock.c:46
#1  0x7376db4c in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x2bd57e0)
    at /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.23-r0/git/nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:115
#2  0x657746dc in gst_pad_pause_task () from /usr/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0
#3  0x652d39d8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstcoreelements.so
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb)
```

Does anyone have any insight as to what is going on?

Comment: Have you updated to the latest release of qt?  Perhaps there is already a bug fix.

Comment: James, have you found cause of this problem. It seems that I am hitting same issue with QT/GStreamer while playing multiple videos in parallel loops.

Comment: any update on this?